# Why do the ASCII control characters look different in local variable window and CMD window

Tags: c++, ascii

The source code is as the following, to output the front 32 characters in ASCII table, namely, the 32 control characters.

```
vector<char> v1;    
for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    v1.push_back(static_cast<char>(i));
    cout << char(i) << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

local variable window:
[image]

CMD window:
[image]
The shapes of ASCII control characters look different. Why?
The system on my computer is Visual Studio 2010 RTMRel and Win 7 with SP1.

Comment: They are not standard. It depends on the font. In some fonts it would just display question marks.

Comment: More importantly, they also depend the code page being used.